# bosh-lite vagrant up fails with no error

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to setup a local cloud foundry instance using bosh-lite on my mac osx laptop V 10.9.4.

```
sh-3.2# vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.7.1
sh-3.2#
```

I unzipped the contents of bosh-lite-master 
 ran the following command

see below

```
sh-3.2#vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

Error Message I got

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Box 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: 2776
The box 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite"]
Error: 
sh-3.2#
```

The error part is empty and I am completely clue less as this is the first time I am working with vagrant

Content of the vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite'
  config.vm.box_version = '2776'

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v, override|
    # To use a different IP address for the bosh-lite director, uncomment this line:
    # override.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.59.4', id: :local
  end

  [:vmware_fusion, :vmware_desktop, :vmware_workstation].each do |provider|
    config.vm.provider provider do |v, override|
      # To use a different IP address for the bosh-lite director, uncomment this line:
      # override.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.54.4', id: :local

      override.vm.box_version = '388'
    end
  end

  config.vm.provider :aws do |v, override|
    # To turn off public IP echoing, uncomment this line:
    # override.vm.provision :shell, id: "public_ip", run: "always", inline: "/bin/true"

    # To turn off CF port forwarding, uncomment this line:
    # override.vm.provision :shell, id: "port_forwarding", run: "always", inline: "/bin/true"
  end
end
```

Comment: You might need to address the earlier error of ‘The box…could not be found’ first.

Comment: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/cloudfoundry/boxes/bosh-lite link shows that there is a "box" available called cloudfoundry/bosh-lite.

Comment: I did vagrant login  created used id and password with above mentioned site vagrant login is successful but still cant run vagrant up, it fails with the same error

Comment: run the command `vagrant box add cloudfoundry/bosh-lite`, can you get the image?

Comment: I tried adding the box.I am getting the same errorThe box 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite"]
Error:

Comment: I do a vagrant login and provide userid password . that succeeds

Answer (score 2):

Please read https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3589

commenting out this block from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.1/lib/vagrant/util/subprocess.rb made it work like a charm

```
if @command[0].downcase.include?(installer_dir)
@logger.info("Command in the installer. Specifying DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH...")
process.environment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] =
"#{installer_dir}/lib:#{ENV["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"]}"
@logger.info("process.environment")
@logger.info(process.environment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"])
@logger.info("end process.environment")
else
@logger.debug("Command not in installer, not touching env vars.")
end
```